# Convert XNA Texture2D to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I need to convert Texture2D to [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and i found one way to do this, but this solution on windows phone 7 has known issue with memory leak in Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg method call. What i have tried: save texture2d in isolatedstorage by calling Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg, then load from isolatedstorage stream with this texture and create BitmapImage from that stream

```
public static void SaveTextureToISF(string fileName, Texture2D texture)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, file)
                    )
                {
                    texture.SaveAsPng(fileStream, texture.Width, texture.Height); //Memory leak Here
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public static BitmapImage LoadTextureFrom(string fileName)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName,
                                                                                         FileMode.Open,
                                                                                         FileAccess.Read, file))
                {
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(fileStream);
                    return bmp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any other solutions, without leaking?

Comment: Solution that i suggested there is workaround how to save textures2d in ISF. But this question about converting texture2d to BitmapImage.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that other solution wasn't applicable on WinPhone.

Comment: I guess the way to do it would involve receiving raw `Texture2D` data using `GetData` method and then converting it manually. I've seen numerous references to http://imagetools.codeplex.com/ for that purpose, but can't find example. This one is for desktop XNA http://www.benbarefield.com/blog/2009/03/04/bitmap-from-texture2d/ but maybe it could give you any ideas..

Comment: Imagetools solved the problem, i'll post solution later

Answer (score 0):

[ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) do the trick.

```
public BitmapImage ConvertTexture2DToBitmapImage(Texture2D texture2D)
        {
            byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * texture2D.Width * texture2D.Height];
            texture2D.GetData(textureData);
            ExtendedImage extendedImage = new ExtendedImage();
            extendedImage.SetPixels(texture2D.Width, texture2D.Height, textureData);
            JpegEncoder encoder = new JpegEncoder();
            using (Stream picStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Encode(extendedImage, picStream);
                picStream.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(picStream);
                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose` MemoryStream, or you'll get another leak :)